# How to get the global/world position of a child object?

Tags: javascript, three.js

How do I get the global position of an Object3D inside another Object3D?

**setup:**

```
var parent = new THREE.Object3D();
parent.position.set(100, 100, 100);

var child = new THREE.Object3D();
child.position.set(100, 100, 100);
parent.add(child);

scene.add(parent);
```

**notes:**

I thought that this would be the way to do it:

```
console.log(child.localToWorld(parent.position));
```

...but it gives me *(100, 100, 100)*, not *(200, 200, 200)*.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You can extract the world position like so:

```
var target = new THREE.Vector3(); // create once an reuse it

child.getWorldPosition( target );
```

`target` will contain the result.

EDIT: updated to three.js r.120

Comment: Thank you WestLangley, following your advice I did this:
**console.log(parent.position.getPositionFromMatrix( child.matrixWorld ))**
But, since the live code is actruly inside a loop that moves things around, this resulted in some weird artifacts, where the velocity of the parent object would increase dramaticly (this only console.logging the childs position)
! Since I don't understand exactly what's going on (will read up on it tho), I ended up doing:
**console.log(parent.position.clone().getPositionFromMatrix( child.matrixWorld ))**
*Thanks again.*

Comment: No, no! Create a separate vector outside the render loop, and assign it the position value inside the render loop.

Comment: Thank you for: scene.updateMatrixWorld(). Always my vector was (0,0,0), because the scene didn't update the matrix. I used the update method and now works fine! :)

Also, getPositionFromMatrix is now setFromMatrixPosition (three.js r65)

Comment: Perfect, that's just what I was missing and looking for. thanks a lot!

Comment: Ah, awesome for children objects I need to update the parent matrixWorld. Perfect. Thank you.

Comment: Following this, I still get 0, 0, 0... Is there anything I might have missed?

Comment: @WestLangley You said "In practice, however, the renderer calls updateMatrixWorld() for you in each render loop, so you don't have to.", but this means that when accessing the `object.matrixWorld` before `renderer.render`, then we're accessing the last frame's matrix, not this frame's matrix?

Answer (score 13):

In threejs **r89** you can just get the world position by [`Object3D.getWorldPosition`](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/core/Object3D.getWorldPosition). I don't know when it was added.

Comment: This works, but as per the other answer make sure to call `parent.updateMatrixWorld()` or `scene.updateMatrixWorld` beforehand.