# How do I get absolute position of Object 3D child? three.js

Tags: three.js, coordinate

I have a Mesh contained inside an Object3D. the mesh initial position is (0,0,100) and the Objects3D's  is (0,0,0) I make the Object3D rotate along its Y axe this makes the Mesh rotate along de center describing an orbit. how can I get the position coordinates of the Mesh with respect to the world at any given time of its trajectory?

cheers

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15098479/how-to-get-the-global-world-position-of-a-child-object

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the global/world position of a child object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15098479/how-to-get-the-global-world-position-of-a-child-object)