# Get position in parent mesh

Tags: javascript, vector, three.js, linear-algebra

I have this sort of meshes (each is the child of above)

```
Scene
     -scene.add(SpaceMesh)
          -SpaceMesh.add(ShipMesh)
```

`SpaceMesh` is moving in scene.
`ShipMesh` is not moving.

if i request `ShipMesh.position.x` it returns 0 (logically)

How can i get coordinates of my `ShipMesh` **in** `SpaceMesh`?

--

Example:

SpaceMesh.position.x = 100

ShipMesh.position.x = 0

Logical result will have to be ShipMesh.*PositionInSpaceMesh*.x = -100

Comment: I think this is what you're asking

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15098479/how-to-get-the-global-world-position-of-a-child-object

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if is the best way, but from:
[how to: get the global/world position of a child object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15098479/how-to-get-the-global-world-position-of-a-child-object)

```
spaceMesh.updateMatrixWorld();
var vector = new THREE.Vector3();
vector.setFromMatrixPosition( spaceMesh.matrixWorld );
vector.multiplyScalar( -1 );
console.log(vector); // my coords in SpaceMesh
```

**If is there better solution, or some "best practices", please correct me, thank you.**