# three js recalculate vector 3 to child object

Tags: three.js

I have `Vector3` in position.

I have `scene` childs:

```
planet = new THREE.Object3D();
city= new THREE.Object3D();
street= new THREE.Object3D();

scene.add(planet);
planet.add(city);
city.add(street);
```

how can i get correct world position of vector in each object(`planet`,`city` and `street` **individually**), with respect to **position,scale and rotation** of each object..

i try  `planet.worldToLocal(new THREE.Vector3( vector.x,vector.y,vector.z )` but it seem to work only from global to child object, not for recalculating from `planet` to `city`.

example:

```
planet.position.set(10,0,0);
city.position.set(10,0,0);
street.position.set(10,0,0);
```

if `myVector` is new `THREE.Vector3(0,10,0)`, i need to get the same position in street object, that should be `(30,10,0)` how to get it by THREE functions??

Answer (score 1):

You can get the world position of an object like so:

```
var position = object.getWorldPosition(); // creates a new THREE.Vector3()
```

or

```
var position = new THREE.Vector3();
object.getWorldPosition( position ); // reuses your existing THREE.Vector3()
```

Note: If you have modified the `position/rotation/scale` of any of the objects in the hierarchy since the last call to `render()`, then you will have to force an update to the world matrices by calling `scene.updateMatrixWorld()`. The renderer calls this for you, otherwise.

three.js r.71

Comment: But i have Vector3 and i need local position of this vector in street object. Which is relative to city relative to planet, relative to world.

That means i have world vector value and need relative to child of child of child.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to use `Vector3.add` in combination with `getWorldPosition()`:

```
planet.position.set(10,0,0);
city.position.set(10,0,0);
street.position.set(10,0,0);

myVector = new THREE.Vector3( 0, 10, 0 ); 
myVector.add( street.getWorldPosition() ); 
console.log( myVector ); // 30, 10, 0
```

Comment: this works only if object have rotation 0,0,0 and fixed scale

Comment: There is also ```getWorldDirection()```. But maybe you want to consider the matrices for that, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/15098870/4977165