# Is there a way to know the "real" position of an a-frame element?

Tags: aframe

I want to find the "real" position of an a-frame element. Not the one shown in the `position` attribute. But the one that's the total of all the parents and relative to the world/scene position?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can look up world coordinates in three.js: https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Object3D.getWorldPosition

It looks something like:

```
var worldPos = new THREE.Vector3();
worldPos.setFromMatrixPosition(el.object3D.matrixWorld);
```

Comment: The link isn't opening. what is matrixWorld?

Answer (score 0):

To give a more complete / updated answer from 2021 / an A-Frame 1.1.0 perspective,

As stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15098479/how-to-get-the-global-world-position-of-a-child-object),

```js
var parent = new THREE.Object3D();
parent.position.set(100, 100, 100);

var child = new THREE.Object3D();
child.position.set(100, 100, 100);
parent.add(child);

scene.add(parent);

var target = new THREE.Vector3(); // create once an reuse it

child.getWorldPosition( target );
```

target will contain the result.

in A-Frame speak, that should be,

```js
AFRAME.registerComponent('some-component', {
  init() {
    const realWorldPosition = this.el.object3D.getWorldPosition(new THREE.Vector3())
  },
};
```